# Shell script to create multiple accounts?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm looking for some help with a school project which needs a shell script to create 10 accounts (5 teaches and 5 students into different groups) along with respected passwords. I'm a true ubuntu noob and only know basic stuff like terminal commands such as cd and ls etc so basic explanations would be greatly appreciated!